# How do I validate a time.Time value using go-playground/validator.v9?

Tags: go

I have this string that I want to validate on my struct, it is optional.

In the validate area is it possible to validate time.Time? Or if some regex is needed how could I do it in the validate part?

```
DOB           time.Time          `json:"dob,omitempty" bson:"dob,omitempty" validate:"omitempty"`
```

It will be passed in by a user via JSON and I wish to confirm that what the user passes in is the correct form:

```
"2001-03-24T16:21:21.269Z"
```

Comment: I'd say it's futile to validate an RFC3339-formatted timestamp using a regexp because you will have hard time constructing a regexp which would enforce proper ranges of individual date and time parts—say, that a month number must be in range 01..12, and day number—in range 01..31, unless it's a month with 30 days or february which has 28 days, unless it's a leap year when it has 29 days, and so on. So, the only proper way to validate stuff like this is to actually _parse_ the string according to the format and check the returned error, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) is not of a `string` kind and therefore you cannot do any "string-like" operations on it. That means that you cannot check whether or not it is of some format, and equally you cannot use regular expressions with it.

If you care about the format that is sent by the user you will have to change the type of the field, i.e. `DOB string` and, if there isn't yet a validator that matches your requirement, you'll have to add a [custom validation function](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9#hdr-Custom_Validation_Functions) because a builtin `regex` validator was left out by [design](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9#hdr-Alias_Validators_and_Tags).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help? Here's what I did for my ISO8601 format datetime

```
CreatedAt           string  `json:"created_at" validate:"ISO8601date"

func IsISO8601Date(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
    ISO8601DateRegexString := "^(?:[1-9]\\d{3}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])|(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])-(?:29|30)|(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31)|(?:[1-9]\\d(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|[13579][26])00)-02-29)T(?:[01]\\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\\d:[0-5]\\d(?:\\.\\d{1,9})?(?:Z|[+-][01]\\d:[0-5]\\d)$"
    ISO8601DateRegex := regexp.MustCompile(ISO8601DateRegexString)
  return ISO8601DateRegex.MatchString(fl.Field().String())
}

validate = validator.New()
_ = validate.RegisterValidation("ISO8601date", IsISO8601Date)
```